# Sum the top 4 values under a specific column that can change

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have the following table (simplified):

[image]

I want to sum the top 4 values for the year 2002. However, the year whose values I want to retrieve can change based on a dropdown list. So, I might want 2004 or 2006 values, for example. In other words, it should look for the column whose header is similar to the value in cell A1.

Thanks.

Comment: What does `Get the top 4 value` mean? Add them up? Average them? String them together?

Comment: Sum them, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the top four values in 4 different cells.

```
=Large(INDEX($C$3:$D$9,,match($H$4,$C$2:$D$2,0)),F5)
```

or a dynamic list might be better... where `L4` represents the number of top values (in your case 4).

```
=arrayformula(Large(INDEX($C$3:$D$9,,match($H$4,$C$2:$D$2,0)),SEQUENCE(L4,1,1,1)))
```

[image]

If you wanted to sum them up, you could change the above formula to be:

```
=sum(arrayformula(Large(INDEX($C$3:$D$9,,match($H$4,$C$2:$D$2,0)),{1,2,3,4})))
```

[Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fzMXF9XFtNs2wJLOwi4VmKB3RmZSq3j_echoTHYcqKo/edit#gid=1602031738)

Comment: I had to make some adaptions, but that worked! Thanks!